# How to extract lines from a text file that contains strings from a list in another file?

Tags: python

I have a file containing population information for a bunch of towns. I have another file that is a list of the names of a subset of those towns. I want to select the population information from the first file using the second file. How would I do this?

Examples:

File 1: `ma-towns.txt`

```
Acton Town;Middlesex;Open town meeting;21924;1735  
Acushnet Town;Bristol;Open town meeting;10303;1860  
Adams Town;Berkshire;Representative town meeting;8485;1778  
Agawam City;Hampden;Mayor-council;28438;1855  
Alford Town;Berkshire;Open town meeting;494;1773  
Amesbury City;Essex;Mayor-council;16283;1668  
Amherst Town;Hampshire;Representative town meeting;37819;1775
```

File 2: `town-list.txt`

```
Acton Town;Middlesex
Adams Town;Berkshire
Amherst Town;Hampshire
```

Desired output would be

```
Acton Town;Middlesex;Open town meeting;21924;1735
Adams Town;Berkshire;Representative town meeting;8485;1778
Amherst Town;Hampshire;Representative town meeting;37819;1775
```

Basically, as said generally, extract the line if it contains the string in one of the lines of file 2.

Comment: Put the contents of `town-list.txt` into a `set`. Then loop through `ma-towns.txt`, checking if the city and county are in the set. If they are, write to the output file.

Comment: Do you have to do this with Python? In the shell it's simply `grep -F -f town-list.txt ma-towns.txt > filtered-towns.txt`

Comment: I can use the shell as well, but both of my txt files, have millions of lines and I get error Killed: 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both previous answers are inefficient because 1/ they read the whole data in memory first, and 2/ they are O((size of ma-towns) x (size of towns_list)).

As we have to check repetitively if a town is in `towns-list.txt`, it is better to make it a `set`, as checking if a value is in a set is O(1) instead of O(n) to check in a list.

We build a set `known_towns` of tuples (sets can't contain mutable lists) that will be `{('Acton Town', 'Middlesex'), ('Adams Town', 'Berkshire'), ('Amherst Town', 'Hampshire')}`.

Then, we iterate on `ma-list.txt`, and check on the fly if the first two fields of the line are in our `known_towns`. If they are, we write the line to the output file.

Note that your files are actually CSV, so we use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to do the parsing. We just have to specify that they use `;` as delimiter, instead of the default `,`.

```
import csv

with open('tmp/town-list.txt', newline='') as towns_file:
    reader = csv.reader(towns_file, delimiter=';')
    known_towns = set(tuple(town) for town in reader)

with open('tmp/ma-towns.txt', newline='') as ma_file, open('tmp/output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    reader = csv.reader(ma_file, delimiter=';')
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        if (tuple(row[:2])) in known_towns:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

We can check that the ouput file is what we expect:

```
print(open('tmp/output.txt').read())
```

Output:

```
Acton Town;Middlesex;Open town meeting;21924;1735  
Adams Town;Berkshire;Representative town meeting;8485;1778  
Amherst Town;Hampshire;Representative town meeting;37819;1775
```